# Making sure an uploaded file meets requirements

Tags: php

I have a website where I allow users to upload photos. For security purposes, I only want users to be able to upload either a jpeg, gif, or png file type. How would I go about writing these conditions?

What I have so far:

```
if ($_FILES['media']['size'] != 0 && //tests file type) {
    //the file is good, upload the file
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the file type.

```
$fileType = $_FILES['media']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['media']['size'];

if (fileSize != 0 ) {
    if ($fileType == 'image/png' || 
        $fileType == 'image/jpg' ||
        $fileType == 'image/gif') {
        //the file is good, upload the file
    }
}
```

And you can find your specific mime-type here: [List of MIME Types by Content Type](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_FILES['media']['type']`

So your complete code:

```
if ($_FILES['media']['size'] != 0 && $_FILES["media"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" && $_FILES["media"]["type"] == "image/gif" && $_FILES["media"]["type"] == "image/png" ) {
     //the file is good, upload the file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

best option is @Siamak.A.M provide to you but instead of that I use mime/types strings in array:

```
$fileType = $_FILES['media']['type'];

// add others.. and you can retrieve this from a conf. file too
$allowed = array('image/gif','image/jpg','image/png');

if (in_array($fileType, $allowed)) {
    //the file is good, upload the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ( $_FILES['media']['size'] != 0 && (
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") ) )
{
    //the file is good, upload the file
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$ext = substr($_FILES['media']['name'], -3)
```

Then check that.

You can compare it against an array of allowed extensions.

```
$allowed = array('jpg', 'gif');
```

And use in_array to check. Just a way however I am sure there are many more.

Comment: Hi, you might have been confused between answers and comments -- this was posted as an answer.